# Squirrel Client with SAP Hybris

Tags: java, spring, hsqldb, sap-commerce-cloud, squirrel-sql

I'm new to SAP Hybris(6.2) and I need some help in looking up the Hsqldb tables (hybris\data\hsqldb). Someone told me to download Squirrel and connect the database driver to it, however, I'm unable to find any tutorial or document on connecting the SAP Hybris HSQLDB in Squirrel Client.

Can anyone please help me with the setup. Will appreciate a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to get the JDBC driver? Or how to specify the JDBC URL? Or how to configure those in Squirrel? Because all 3 of those should have lots of examples online, so all you need is to combine them.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any extra tools to inspect HSQLDB.

In the HSQLDB JAR in `platform/lib/dbdriver` you have a DB visualizer.

You just have to start it using `java -jar hsqldb-2.3.4.jar`.

It will open a GUI. [image]

In type set `HSQL Database Engine Standalone`.

Then set your DB location in URL.
`jdbc:hsqldb:file:<hybris_data_dir>/hsqldb/mydb` .

OOTB hybris use SA user with no password.

If you have configured a "in-memory" DB then replace `:file:` by `:mem:`

Comment: thank you, i'm able to connect to HSQL Database Manager however on the left hand side i couldnt see any by default table for the recipes that i've build, like in the screenshot that you have attached has so many tables. Its showing me only  one folder called Properties.

Comment: If you have no table, then you probably put a wrong URL, or your database is not initialized yet.

Comment: So below is the screenshot, i've inititalized the system and website is running. However i am not get the setting configured to show the HSQL tables

Comment: You can't put a screenshot in the comment. Also you can't connect to the visualizer if the DB is already used by hybris in "file" mode. You have to shutdown hybris first.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know how to run the flexible & sql query through HAC. Still, if you are looking for **GUI query tool**/**client** for HSQLDB then HSQL has built-in GUI query tool called `DatabaseManager`. You can explore the database with the default hsqldb DatabaseManager.

You have to run `java -cp ../lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManager`

Like

**UNIX/Mac**

```
cd $HYBRIS_HOME_DIR/hybris; java -cp ./bin/platform/lib/dbdriver/hsqldb*.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManager --url jdbc:hsqldb:file:./data/hsqldb/mydb &
```

**Windows**

```
cd %HYBRIS_HOME_DIR%\hybris & start /B java -cp .\bin\platform\lib\dbdriver\* org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManager --url jdbc:hsqldb:file:.\data\hsqldb\mydb
```